# SSIS Lookup fails validation on x64 machine

Tags: ssis, 32bit-64bit, lookup

I have an SSIS package that is using a Lookup:

- Target and Source use **OLE DB** connections, looking at *SQL Server 2008 R2*.
- Lookup is using **Full cache**, and an **OLE DB connection manager** (defaults).
- The Lookup looks for a key of *13 columns*. One of them is of type **Date**, which fails validation later.

It all works well from my machine, naturally.
I can install the package on production, but when running it it quickly fails on validation of the Lookup:

> input column [ColumnName] (238) and reference column named [ColumnName] have incompatible data types

This is clearly a lie - they have the same types. It looks like this is a known problem of the Lookup component:

- [Lookup claims incompatible data types](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/f468442c-85a2-4db3-85c9-1add39979fb8)
- [SSIS Lookup Component Error: output column ‘x’ and reference column named ‘y’ have incompatible data types](http://coastalcoder.wordpress.com/2007/07/26/ssis-lookup-component-error-output-column-x-and-reference-column-named-y-have-incompatible-data-types/)

In both cases, some people suggested running the package in 32 bits solved their problem. However, my package fails connection to the server when running in 32 bits...

What am I missing? Should I install additional x86 providers?
Is there a good way of fixing the Lookup?

Comment: What were you looking up against (ole db connection to X or a cache connection manager)? What were the data types involved?

Comment: @billinkc - Good questions! Thanks. I should also mention the task is complete for me by now, and I can't really test for all possible solutions - but it may still benefit someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I was able to open the Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell on the production server, and run the package through there. Since this is a one-time migration job, I don't really mind.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but if anyone stumbles here, here's my solution.

I was getting this same answer, and in the query for the lkp, I explicitely converted the problem data type using a CAST statement.  I too was having no problems in debug, but was getting the error when it was deployed and run on SSMS.  This fixed it for me.